# Why my react-redux component doesn't render when the api requisition returns?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm studying React-Redux and creating a store frontend to test my skills. However, I'm having a problem that I can not solve.

My API was returning all products that I have on the database, so I changed it to filter by category. So I changed my *ProductList* component and *SingleProduct* component to reflect that change. After that, *ProductList* doesn't render when the API call returns. My *App.jsx* is the main component that renders the entire page, the *ProductsList* was rendered using *{this.props.children}* but to send a category id to the component, I changed it to__ as can be seen below:

**App.jsx**

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        let category = 600;
        return (
            <div className="page">
                <Helmet titleTemplate="Ecommerce - %s" />
                <Header />
                <Navbar />
                <MainBanner />
                <Tabs />
                <ProductList category={category} />
                <Footer />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**ProductList.jsx**

```
class ProductList extends Component {
    addToCart(id) {
        this.props.addToCart(id);
    }
    addToWishlist(id) {
        this.props.addToWishlist(id);
    }
    removeFromCart(id) {
        this.props.removeFromCart(id);
    }
    removeFromWishlist(id) {
        this.props.removeFromWishlist(id);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchProducts(this.props.category);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="tab1">
                <div className="category-products slider-home">
                    <ul className="home_slider products-grid products-grid--max-2-col slick-initialized slick-slider">
                        {this.props.products.map((product) => {
                            <ProductItem key={product.id}
                                product={product}
                                addToCart={this.addToCart.bind(this)}
                                addToWishlist={this.addToWishlist.bind(this)}
                                                            removeFromWishlist={this.removeFromWishlist.bind(this)}
                                removeFromCart={this.removeFromCart.bind(this)}
                                wishlist={this.props.wishlist}
                                cart={this.props.cart} />
                        })}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
    addToCart: (id) => dispatch(addToCard(id)),
    addToWishlist: (id) => dispatch(addToWishlist(id)),
    removeFromCart: (id) => dispatch(removeFromCart(id)),
    removeFromWishlist: (id) => dispatch(removeFromWishlist(id)),
    fetchProducts: () => dispatch(fetchProducts(ownProps.category)),
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        products: state.ProductsReducer.data,
        wishlist: state.WishlistReducer.data,
        cart: state.CartReducer.data
    }
}
```

**fetchProducts.js**

```
const requestProducts = () => {
    return {
        type: 'REQUEST_PRODUCTS',
    }
}

const receiveProducts = (data) => {
    return {
        type: 'RECEIVE_PRODUCTS',
        payload:data
    }
}

export const fetchProducts = (data) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(requestProducts());
        return axios.get('http://localhost/api/products/getProducts?category_id='+data, {})
           .then(response => response)
           .then(json => {
               dispatch(receiveProducts(json.data))
           })
       }
 }
```

**ProductsReducer.js**

```
const ProductsReducer = (state = {fetching:false,data:[]}, action) => {
   switch(action.type){
      case 'REQUEST_PRODUCTS':
        return Object.assign({}, state,{
          fetching:true,
          data:[]
        })
        break
      case 'RECEIVE_PRODUCTS':
        return Object.assign({}, state,{
          fetching:false,
          data:action.payload
        })
        break
      default:
      return state
   }
}
```

Finally, the errors i'm getting and the logging results:
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzTfk.png)

After editing, got no errors but component not rendering yet.[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL9oL.png)

**Edit 0:**

- Changed *ProductList* *componentWillMount()* to *componentDidMount*
- Added another console image

**Edit 1:**
- Changed ProductList.jsx to most recent version. (still not rendering the list)

Comment: `<!-- -->` commenting is not used in JSX, and I'm not sure if it even works.

Comment: Have you read error? Seems like you are doing weird things inside `render` method in a `ProductList` component

Comment: and also make API calls inside _`componentDidMount`_, i.e., call `dispatch(fetchProducts())` from inside `componentDidMount`

Comment: The comment is just to show how it was before the changes. It's not really in the file.

Comment: Changed the call from _componentWillMount_ to _componentDidMount_ Got no errors but component still not rendering...